# If condition on shell not working , not sure what is the mistake I am doing?

Tags: bash, shell, for

I have a requirement to perform specific set of tasks based on server , So I want to have the condition(s) defined based on server. Here is the script I came up with and I have read multiple blogs and couldn`t find any mistake from my script. Can you guide on what I am overlooking here ?

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER_NAME=`hostname -s`
hostname -s
DBServer=(servr1 servr2 servr3 servr4)
#AppServer=[hqidlfdiwa01 , hqiqlfdiwa01]
echo "Values of DBServer seeing is ${DBServer[*]}"
Values of DBServer seeing is servr1 servr2 servr3 servr4
for i in ${DBServer[*]}
do
  echo "current value in I is $i"
  echo "The server name found is $SERVER_NAME"
  if [$SERVER_NAME == $i]
  then
    echo "I am on one of the servers and it is $i"
  fi
done
```

Output I see on server is

```
current value in I is servr1
The server name found is servr1
-bash: [servr1: command not found
current value in I is servr2
The server name found is servr1
-bash: [servr1: command not found
current value in I is servr3
The server name found is servr1
-bash: [servr1: command not found
current value in I is servr4
The server name found is servr1
-bash: [servr1: command not found
```

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: @John1024 this is a life saver. I never knew this is existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell, spaces matter.

Replace:

```
if [$SERVER_NAME == $i]
```

with:

```
if [ "$SERVER_NAME" = "$i" ]
```

Without the spaces, the shell thinks that you want to run a command named `[$SERVER_NAME` (such as `[servr1`) with arguments `==` and `$i]`.  With the space, the shell runs the *test* command, denoted by `[`.

Also, always place shell variables in double quotes unless you understand what shell expansions would be applied and you explicitly want them to be applied.

Lastly, while bash accepts either `==` or `=` to mean string-equal inside `[...]`, other shells only understand `=`.  For portability, it is best practice to use `=` for string-equal inside `[...]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the Tips , really helpful .